# Ruby 2.1: Composing a Bicycle of Parts -> private method `select' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, oop, conventions

I am getting an error when running this code. The Following is the output:

```
L
Bicycle#Ex3.rb:32:in `spares': private method `select' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from Bicycle#Ex3.rb:10:in `spares'
    from Bicycle#Ex3.rb:111:in `<main>'
```

Here is the code:

```
class Bicycle
  attr_reader :size, :parts

  def initialize(args={})
    @size     = args[:size]
    @parts    = args[:parts]
  end

  def spares
    parts.spares # return an array
  end

  def lead_days
    1
  end
  #...
end

class Parts
  attr_reader :parts

  def initialize(args={})
    @parts = parts
  end

  def size
    parts.size
  end

  def spares
    parts.select{|part| part.needs_spare} 
  end
end

class Part
  attr_reader :name, :description, :needs_spare

  def initialize(args)
    @name      = args[:name]
    @description = args[:description]
    @needs_spare = args.fetch(:needs_spare, true)
  end
end

class RoadBikeParts < Parts
  attr_reader :tape_color

  def post_initialize(args)
    @tape_color = args[:tape_color]
  end

  def local_spares
    {tape_color: tape_color}
  end

  def default_tire_size
    '23'
  end
end 

class MountainBikeParts < Parts
  attr_reader :front_shock, :rear_shock

  def post_initialize(args)
    @front_shock = args[:front_shock]
    @rear_shock = args[:rear_shock]
  end

  def local_spares
      { rear_shock: rear_shock}
  end

  def default_tire_size
    '2.1'
  end
end

chain = Part.new(
                 name: 'chain',
                 description: '10 speed')

road_tire = Part.new(
                     name: 'tape_size', 
                     description: '23')
tape = Part.new(
               name: 'tape_color',
               description: 'red')
mountain_tire = Part.new(
                         name: 'tire_size',
                         description: '2.1')
rear_shock = Part.new(
                      name: 'rear_shock',
                      description: 'Fox')

front_shock = Part.new(
                       name: 'front_shock',
                       description: 'Manitou',
                       needs_spare: false)

road_bike_part = Parts.new([chain, road_tire, tape])                                

road_bike = Bicycle.new(
                        size: 'L',
                        parts: Parts.new([chain,
                                          road_tire,
                                          tape]))

puts road_bike.size
#puts road_bike.parts.size
puts road_bike.spares.size
```

It is clear this line --> puts road_bike.spares.size is given the error NoMethodError, however, I am not sure how I can make a work around to correct this issue for this example. The spares method is returning an array of Part objects, however it seems my problem lies in the fact the spares method .select is private from the calling object.

Any advice to revise this code would be great. Thanks.

Comment: The exceptions says it clearly, you're calling `spares` method on nil. Looking at the code I also doubt you have any idea what you're doing. Why isn't it AR?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I am not sure what you are referring to when you ask about AR? Could you clarify please?

Comment: This post is about plain Ruby rather than Rails, hence these aren't AR (ActiveRecord) instances. Though in Rails you can also have classes which aren't AR subclasses @Michal Szyndel ;)

Comment: @fivedigit I know that but if it looks like AR and quacks like AR I may assume something fishy is going on, right? And you must admit that it resembles AR heavily...

Comment: @Michal Szyndel, That is true. If I'm not mistaken though, this code is actually based on an example from Practical Object Oriented Design in Ruby by Sandy Metz

Comment: @fivedigit, you are correct. She takes a very basic example and shows the beauty in how the ruby programming language can be utilized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is that `Parts#parts` is `nil`. You're getting the error on this line:

```
# parts is nil
parts.select{|part| part.needs_spare}
```

In the initializer of `Parts`, its `parts` attribute does not get assigned properly:

```
def initialize(args={})
  @parts = parts
end
```

So when being initialized, it assigns `@parts` with the value of `parts`. But since `parts` is not a local variable there, it calls the `Parts#parts` method, which returns `nil`.

If you change the initializer to the following:

```
def initialize(parts)
  @parts = parts
end
```

You'll be able to run the code. But subclasses of `Parts` seem to expect a `Hash` in the initializer, rather than an `Array` like their super class does though.

Comment: Thank you for the response and followup on the subclasses. As I follow through these examples the next part was addressing the array issue and the possible options for refactoring the code.